# Unable to display the database on a web framework

Tags: python, flask

I am new to python flask and I faced some problem in my code. I need to extract the database from a mcu_aurix_git.db file and display it on a web framework by using flask. However, the code is not running. I expect my database is in a table form. At the same time, I need to execute some actions like "Delete" and "Update" action on a particular row of a database. Anyone can help me? This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

def connect_db(db):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db) 
    return  conn.cursor()

@app.route('/') 
def index():    
    db ='mcu_aurix_git.db'
    c = connect_db(db)
    cur = c.execute('SELECT * FROM mcu_aurix')    
    return render_template('flask.html', rows = cur.fetchall())

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/delete/<int:id>')
def delete(id):
    task_to_delete = Todo.query.get_or_404(id)

    try:
        db.session.delete(task_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    except:
        return 'There was a problem deleting that task'

@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update(id):
    task = Todo.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task.content = request.form['content']

        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except: 
            return 'There was an issue updating your task' 
    else:
        return render_template('update.html', task=task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The error I got is

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: flask.html
```

Any suggestion to improve my code? Thanks.

flask.html

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>project</th>
            <th>branch</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>subject</th>
            <th>owner name</th>
            <th>owner email</th>
            <th>owner_username</th>
            <th>url</th>
            <th>commitMessage</th>
            <th>createdOn</th>
            <th>lastUpdated</th>
            <th>open</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>current_date</th>          
          </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {% for row in rows %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{project_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{branch_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{id_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{subject_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{owner_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{owner_email}}</td>
                    <td>{{owner_username}}</td>
                    <td>{{url_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{commitMessage_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_createdOn}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_lastUpdated}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_open}}</td>
                    <td>{{status_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{current_date}}</td>
                  </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: doc: [Templates](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATE

On your root folder of your project do you have a subfolder named 'templates' and inside the 'flask.html'?

- Project
- templates
- flask.html

Try something like this on your flask.html:

```
 {% for row in rows %}
 {{ row.id }}{{ row.content }} {{ row.date_created }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Kostas, do I need to move the flask.html into templates?

Comment: Yes! Flask has as a default folder for the html files the templates folder on project's root path.

Comment: Ok. I try again.

Comment: There is another error occured, that is jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '}'. Can I know what is this?

Comment: Hi Kostas, I could display the row title in the web framework. However, the content from the database file couldn't load into the web framework and I couldn't perform the "update" and "delete" action for each row. How can I solve this problem? By the way, I have updated my flask.html into my question. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, replace your <td> values likewise '<td>{{project_name}}</td>' to '<td>{{ row.project_name }}</td>' and secondly you are using RAW sql in your select query and your class, so you can just use a RAW sql to delete and update too. for example cur = c.execute('delete from mcu_aurix where id = %s') %id and conn.commit()

Comment: Hi, I have changed the <td> values to the <td> values that you mentioned. However, the content of the database file still cannot be displayed on the web framework, still only the row title is displayed on the web framework.